# pyvenv & pip not installing into local site-packages

Tags: django, python-3.x, pip

I'm test driving the Django 1.6b, Python 3.3.2 (compiled from source) and [pyvenv](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/venv.html) with Ubuntu 12.04.

Every time I try and install perform a `pip install [package]` the package attempts to install itself globally rather than into my local environment. A simple workflow is as follows:

`$ pyvenv environments/roebk`

`$ source environments/roebk/bin/activate`

`$ (roebk) pip install south`

`error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/south': Permission denied`

I've double checked that I'm using the correct version of pip.

`$ pip -V
pip 1.4 from /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip-1.4-py3.3.egg (python 3.3)`

Am I missing anything obvious?

Comment: Have you modified the `pyvenv` script somehow? Because it seems to me that your `pip` is still global even after you activate the `venv`.

Comment: Hi Hieu, I haven't tinkered with the pyvenv script. I have just attempted a local package install via virtualenv (as I'm more familiar with that tool) and it installed locally first time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you install `setuptools` and `pip` into the environment? `virtualenv` installs `setuptools` and `pip` automatically into a new environment.

```
$ virtualenv qwerty 
New python executable in qwerty/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done. 
Installing pip...............done.
$
```

According to the [pyvenv docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/venv.html) you need to install them into the new environment manually.

> Common installation tools such as Distribute and pip work as expected
>   with venvs - i.e. when a venv is active, they install Python packages
>   into the venv without needing to be told to do so explicitly. **Of
>   course, you need to install them into the venv first**: this could be
>   done by running distribute_setup.py with the venv activated, followed
>   by running easy_install pip. Alternatively, you could download the
>   source tarballs and run python setup.py install after unpacking, with
>   the venv activated.

Comment: Right, so fire up your `venv` or in my case `pyvenv-3.3`, and install `setuptools`.  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/ `distribute_setup.py` was merged back into `ez_setup.py` with [install info here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/#unix-based-systems-including-mac-os-x) .  Then use `~VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/easy_install pip` to install pip.  Be sure to use the `easy_install` and `pip` *inside your venv* for all this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Upon [the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/venv.html) I thought Python 3.4 would install pip automatically, but it seems, it doesn't: 
Changed in version 3.4: Installs pip by default, added the --without-pip and --copies options

EDIT: Somehow I managed to use a Python3.3.2 version also installed on that machine. With Python3.4, it works as expected.